# В Ubuntu при команде ifconfig нет серого IP addr: 10.0.2.15

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image: Без него не могу присоединиться к виртуалки]
Сижу в виртуальной машине и не могу присоединиться по SSH потому что нет серого IP. Сеть не хочу сбрасывать. Может есть какие-то варианты?

Comment: пропишите серый айпи в настройках интерфейса, какая версия убунту?

Comment: по-другому у вас вряд ли что-то выйдет

Comment: Ubuntu server 21.04

Comment: sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

там уже enp0s3:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.3/24

к примеру, будет третий адрес в первой подсети, если у вас уже что-то похожее прописано там, то останется только перезапустить сетевую службу - 1. sudo netplan generate 2. sudo netplan apply

Comment: #This is the network config....network:   ethernets:   enp0s3:     dhcp4:  true       version:2  и нет ничего..

Comment: А откуда он там должен был взяться? Как у вас настроена сеть в виртуалке?

Comment: Он был и все работало нормально. Я играл с удаленным доступом и настройки сбились..

Comment: если машина без нужных файлов - запустите новую с чистым образом, сэкономите время, ну или пропишите как здесь: https://dondub.com/2021/04/router-na-ubuntu-server-21-04/ Это так просто загуглить, зачем на SO задавать такие вопросы?

Answer (score 0):

`UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST` - сеть настроенна, но кабель не подключен.  В настройках виртуалки галочку сеть включенна нужно поставить. Возможно, следует ещё проверить настройки виртуальной сети.